# How to make the Delete key work in mysql prompt?

Tags: ssh, mysql, putty

I use Putty to connect to a Linux machine from a Windows machine via ssh. The keyboard works just fine in Bash.

But in the mySQL prompt, the <kbd>Del</kbd> key prints a `~` intsead of erasing a character.

Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug (missing feature) in the [EditLine](http://www.thrysoee.dk/editline/) library, which is sometimes used by MySQL:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=294, 
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=33091

Sadly, my MySQL installation does use this lib:

> `$ mysql --version`
>   mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.96, for suse-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  **EditLine** wrapper

so I guess I'll have to accept that.